# Как убрать звук из формы?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Пишу Приложение для хранения браузерных игр. Приложение прогружает три наиболее посещаемых мной игры в скрытых формах с браузером. Некоторые страницы с играми содержат рекламу со звуком или загружаются со звуком и в итоге получается каша. Как убрать звук из формы?

Comment: а зачем грузить в скрытых формах приложения?

Comment: Компонент `WebBrowser` в WinForms является оберткой COM объекта, поэтому скорее всего убрать звук не получится

Comment: в WebBrowser.Document найдите теги с рекламой и удалите их.

Comment: @Stack Некоторые сайты сразу запускают игру на странице и во многих из них есть музыка при загрузке. Я думаю можно ли убрать звук со всей формы сразу? Ведь эти отдельные браузеры находятся в разных формах

Comment: @Алексей _"отдельные браузеры находятся в разных формах"_ -- значит надо к каждому подключиться и убрать теги.  другой вариант: пропустить трафик из WebBrowser'ов через FiddlerCore и фильтровать аудиопоток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18348015/1985167), глушит аудио аутпут всего приложения:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinformsWB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr h, out uint dwVolume);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr h, uint dwVolume);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // сохраняем текущую громкость
            uint _savedVolume;
            waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out _savedVolume);

            this.FormClosing += delegate 
            {
                // восстанавливаем громкость на выходе
                waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, _savedVolume);
            };

            // глушим
            waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://youtube.com");
        }
    }
}
```