# WebBrowser как отключить щелчок при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Как программно отключить звук щелчка при переходе на другую страницу?
Отключение через настройки Windows не вариант. Компонент браузер сам ходит по ссылкам и при переходе раздаются щелки. Как их отключить?

Answer (score 2):

Звуки в компоненте `WebBrowser` завязаны на систему, к сожалению. Поэтому у вас есть несколько вариантов:

- Отключать их в настройках системы
- Программно [отключать в настройках IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/737280/1985167) (только в версии 7+)
- Программно [отключать аудио аутпут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488756/106) для вашего приложения